# Change user rights in teletbon

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to change the rights of group members/administrators according to the example in the telethon documentation:
https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/chats-and-channels.html#admin-permissions,
But the problem is that the required ChannelAdminRights class simply does not exist and I get an ImportError error: cannot import name 'ChannelAdminRights' from 'telethon.tl.types'
How do I change my member rights?  (I use Google Translate)

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation. The official ones are at docs.telethon.dev

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=restrict#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.edit_permissions

Here's the code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import telethon
from datetime import timedelta

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "dddddd"

with TelegramClient("anon", api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.start()
    client.connect()
    chat_id = client.get_entity("username / chat_id / Title").id
    users = client.get_participants(chat_id)
    client.edit_permissions(chat_id, users[3], timedelta(minutes = 60), send_messages = False)
```

With this code, a bot/userbot will mute for one hour an user.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's exactly what I need! I just ran this code and faced with the problem that this method works only for channels and megpgroup, and I have a chat...
Error text:
raise ValueError('You must pass either a channel or a supergroup')
ValueError: You must pass either a channel or a supergroup

Comment: You can convert the group into a supergroup. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmUYZ3wn_5M